# Matrix won't fill with values - R

Tags: r

I'm trying to take monthly stock return data and multiply them into yearly data. When I run my for loops I get no errors and they seem to work but the hpryearly matrix remains filled with NA when I view it and not with the actual numbers it should be calculating.

My code is:

```
data=read.csv(file.choose())
#Make data more readable. Rows become dates, columns become PERMNOs.
data4=dcast(data,date~PERMNO,value.var='RET')
datamatrix=data.matrix(data4)
#HPR
datamatrix2=datamatrix+1
#Fill in missing values
datamatrix2[is.na(datamatrix2)]=1
datamatrix2[datamatrix2==""]=1
#Calculate yearly HPR
hpryearly=matrix(nrow=nrow(datamatrix2)/12,ncol=ncol(datamatrix2))
for (i in 1:(nrow(datamatrix2)/12)){
  for (j in (i*12-11):(i*12)){
    hpryearly[i,]=hpryearly[i,]*datamatrix2[j,]
  }    
}
```

datamatrix2 looks like this:

```
date    10001   10002   10025   10026   10028   10032   10042   10044   10051   10056   10065   10066   10078   10085   10092   10100   10104   10107   10113   10116   10119   10137   10138   10143   10145   10147   10151   10158   10163   10180   10182   10200   10201   10205   10207   10211   10220   10223   10225   10232   10238   10239   10252   10253   10257   10258   10259   10271   10272   10290   10294   10297   10299   10302   10304   10308   10318   10324   10333   10342   10353   10355   10362   10363   10371   10375   10382   10383   10395   10397   10404   10421   10443   10463   10488   10501   10507   10514   10516   10517   10530   10547   10550   10560   10562   10563   10568   10574   10586   10597   10606   10623   10629   10638   10644   10645   10649   10650   10656
```

1   20060132    0.983505    1.029851    1.040000    1.019357    1.005025    1.244943    1.287671    0.855861    1.187391    1.003293    1.038247    1   1.073986    1.028724    1.094328    1.018335    1.029484    1.076482    1.000000    1.000000    1.003708    1.099210    1.061086    1.004280    1.031409    0.983847    1.000000    1.000000    1.191500    0.921053    1.040899    1.187500    1.000000    0.990202    1.088143    1.038733    1.000000    1.000000    0.960779    0.988636    0.988764    1.032922    1.033649    1.094071    1.375000    1.058511    1.063719    0.984848    1.125899    1.040000    1.144518    1.040706    1.035764    1.188070    0.997369    1.062054    1.124623    1.002261    1.037500    1.050525    0.934708    0.944273    1.011940    1.803249    1.036704    0.929256    1.177281    1.083942    1.024306    1.095939    1.078125    1.086374    0.950486    0.986460    0.893581    1.260589    1.100783    0.919298    1.277372    1.131443    1.244042    0.955556    1.081633    0.960396    1.011101    1.158196    0.945058    1.342474    1.072270    1.051948    1.111918    1.025669    0.970046    1.369110    1.218543    0.989316    1.076447    1   1.094225
2   20060229    0.989463    1.065700    1.035385    1.121202    0.997500    1.185447    0.872340    1.107681    0.898230    1.002645    1.003070    1   0.926667    1.004380    0.990099    1.068126    0.988067    0.957727    1.000000    1.000000    0.997537    1.027881    1.004579    1.153409    1.071756    1.046269    1.000000    1.000000    1.072330    1.107143    1.007276    0.936842    1.000000    1.027288    1.040501    1.038445    1.000000    1.000000    1.039354    0.954320    0.972727    1.000000    1.027467    0.921965    0.993939    0.989950    0.898533    1.023692    0.856869    0.955370    0.962085    0.992442    0.990594    1.049025    0.992252    0.987179    0.960626    0.977446    1.012048    0.960048    1.150735    0.934907    0.938053    1.251251    1.279225    1.014806    0.934200    1.084175    1.049922    0.901624    1.140580    0.992803    1.066415    0.819608    0.982987    1.088000    1.052444    1.145038    1.010159    1.116173    0.893745    0.968992    0.977358    0.905122    0.955505    0.965010    1.011919    0.808897    0.988960    1.049383    1.065024    0.959299    0.979216    0.854302    0.918478    1.041037    1.098172    1   1.029167
3   20060332    1.170394    1.009973    1.223997    0.991605    1.127820    1.119487    1.060976    1.028509    1.141215    0.977580    1.021505    1   1.230216    1.008177    1.011177    1.129841    1.102254    1.012653    1.000000    1.000000    0.980247    0.946588    1.022271    0.988300    1.044444    0.972183    1.000000    1.000000    1.041569    1.045161    0.888755    0.831461    1.000000    1.025199    1.044486    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.039716    1.056803    1.019276    1.072727    1.066337    0.995298    1.006098    1.274112    0.992517    0.996667    1.031320    1.134258    1.014251    1.050993    0.951709    0.954392    1.057172    1.031712    1.074523    0.969426    1.363095    1.000000    0.883387    1.012500    0.987421    1.530000    1.127937    1.015379    0.999443    1.124224    1.057569    0.945445    1.011436    1.011391    1.009297    0.923445    0.932692    1.045000    1.013091    0.928333    1.060845    1.000571    1.210408    1.560000    0.949807    1.189112    1.051848    1.053152    1.044712    0.737935    1.023256    0.884706    1.015651    1.042160    1.051243    1.026637    0.934911    1.063278    1.172135    1   0.994602
4   20060429    0.905369    0.932731    1.069499    1.019649    1.031111    1.159436    1.172299    0.978474    0.965468    1.348061    1.002256    1   0.974659    1.000000    1.002327    0.950806    1.065741    0.887541    1.000000    1.000000    1.016456    1.052585    1.076461    0.827726    0.993687    0.991196    1.000000    1.000000    0.986822    1.080247    0.994852    0.943243    1.000000    1.002785    1.022431    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.995907    1.024444    1.146132    0.950659    0.989736    0.979528    1.042424    0.709163    0.951337    0.996504    1.032538    1.010441    1.080139    0.983932    1.016249    1.012389    0.937381    0.973001    1.002601    0.909848    0.816594    1.000000    1.000000    1.009259    1.000000    0.682353    1.076389    1.052039    1.096100    0.895028    0.953831    1.046271    1.028894    0.805261    1.117122    1.411917    1.000000    0.979155    0.997082    0.951526    1.079941    0.995918    0.966457    0.805128    0.752033    1.050602    1.015518    0.947379    1.032483    0.965779    0.983636    0.875000    0.941387    1.150714    0.981287    0.872471    1.088608    0.911424    1.095335    1   1.084125
5   20060532    0.989548    1.049371    0.939415    0.944526    1.081897    0.902893    1.176586    0.878964    1.166915    0.989742    0.971493    1   0.926000    1.000000    0.964016    0.860899    0.974640    0.941615    1.000000    1.000000    0.941470    1.023576    0.939541    1.077155    0.974279    0.947446    1.000000    1.000000    0.892966    0.763810    0.988834    0.876791    1.000000    0.935556    0.944737    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.926027    1.012292    0.882500    0.990491    1.000314    0.682476    0.889535    0.938202    1.001441    1.011747    1.010504    0.923000    0.907258    1.032924    0.950704    0.884615    1.023448    0.968111    0.894942    0.972858    0.957219    1.000000    0.808318    1.027523    1.000000    1.000383    0.740645    0.994043    0.877764    1.027778    0.871275    1.015120    1.025641    0.985575    1.150393    0.990826    1.000000    1.010932    0.959866    1.130189    1.146670    1.004672    0.916410    0.891720    1.021622    0.796351    1.005864    1.016618    0.957303    0.928346    0.927577    0.851064    1.004677    0.968405    0.975268    1.018145    0.985465    0.920564    0.992222    1   0.957447
6   20060631    0.923613    1.088561    1.009515    1.024575    0.952191    0.869819    0.841667    0.962222    1.067688    1.020336    0.997674    1   0.896328    1.000000    0.975918    0.940887    1.018987    1.028698    1.000000    1.000000    0.957672    1.016452    0.959545    1.151642    0.978630    0.857031    1.000000    1.000000    0.940925    0.992519    1.055081    0.954248    1.000000    1.042515    0.966565    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.959595    1.048571    0.990368    1.085106    1.025134    1.254417    0.915033    0.964072    0.678417    0.997568    0.855856    1.151860    1.129286    1.005937    0.992296    0.957839    0.972139    1.049805    1.086956    1.026050    0.949721    1.000000    0.970917    0.922262    1.000000    1.157411    0.921022    0.990637    0.987840    0.750751    1.063076    1.043400    0.972619    1.068876    0.987371    0.959259    1.000000    0.998008    0.962108    1.205342    0.993024    0.988163    1.048760    0.950000    0.925926    0.794203    0.956300    1.120964    0.970892    0.929601    0.868368    1.032143    0.978705    1.089957    0.977681    1.059970    1.005900    0.870349    1.078387    1   0.914379
7   20060732    1.157417    1.171283    1.336326    0.909888    0.962343    0.728442    0.881188    1.093918    0.868421    1.001993    1.006216    1   1.048193    1.000000    1.004935    1.052356    1.033126    1.032618    1.000000    1.000000    1.074306    1.107364    1.092568    1.013046    0.960298    0.925251    1.000000    1.000000    0.844859    1.007538    0.970504    1.027397    1.000000    0.962091    0.992225    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.021265    1.009698    0.803776    0.986274    1.044349    0.914554    0.892857    0.944099    0.962884    1.007010    0.833198    1.000315    0.973118    1.019261    0.965960    1.044704    0.977482    0.988372    0.991556    1.120065    1.000000    1.000000    1.013825    0.990706    1.000000    1.061218    0.983607    1.026087    0.621336    0.908000    0.970105    0.888012    0.550796    0.977823    0.772759    0.830116    1.000000    0.969749    1.003622    0.768698    1.065892    0.908715    0.846293    0.992481    0.937143    0.927007    1.020187    1.057966    1.070732    0.902372    0.939481    0.865052    0.868256    0.928603    1.048827    0.991042    0.914956    0.937609    0.985116    1   1.002890
8   20060832    1.123574    0.965806    0.980743    1.052509    1.304348    0.795345    0.898876    0.987333    0.990358    1.010125    1.024710    1   1.147126    1.000000    0.942296    1.004975    1.046092    1.071904    1.000000    1.000000    0.971558    1.016809    1.066570    1.116202    1.006379    1.147783    1.000000    1.000000    0.960043    0.972569    0.938408    1.076667    1.000000    1.044179    1.021548    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.006481    1.121202    1.130961    0.983698    1.007078    0.929158    1.040000    0.967105    1.538546    1.005798    1.292517    1.134258    0.915340    1.023041    1.055951    1.029625    1.055323    1.062588    0.892425    0.968558    1.000000    1.000000    0.936364    0.989967    1.000000    1.142813    0.668590    0.968785    1.112736    1.039648    1.083980    1.029444    0.966667    0.996701    1.001044    0.976744    1.000000    0.927899    1.102391    1.075676    0.937955    0.979727    1.136191    1.098485    0.932927    1.062992    1.009690    1.037063    0.922551    1.134479    0.993827    0.860000    1.067628    1.005643    1.003930    1.042031    0.996795    1.077586    0.875264    1   1.015850
9   20060930    0.945830    1.055367    0.957763    0.984370    0.833333    0.968719    0.900000    0.972760    0.915160    1.021656    1.022693    1   0.991984    1.000000    1.074919    1.000990    1.132822    1.064202    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.962386    1.089196    1.006976    1.056302    1.028326    1.000000    1.000000    1.208099    0.925641    1.047005    1.052632    1.000000    0.979827    0.990412    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.034573    1.030610    1.011328    0.988975    0.956955    1.090608    0.984538    0.891156    1.070150    0.988471    0.974436    0.977494    1.139087    0.975976    0.915025    1.136189    1.007987    1.013152    0.993973    1.018723    1.111765    1.000000    1.070388    1.017899    1.000000    0.930423    1.046021    1.008439    1.070369    0.995763    1.041884    1.012142    1.119540    1.015722    1.125577    1.028548    1.000000    1.070409    1.100245    1.015075    0.920088    0.974930    0.985331    0.868965    0.875817    0.914815    1.032150    0.997328    0.990370    1.069519    0.986957    0.893023    1.024186    0.998592    1.017715    0.972424    0.926045    0.884364    1.006022    1   0.998582
10  20061032    1.007273    0.878810    1.255781    1.074277    0.948000    1.141667    1.111111    0.959469    1.179331    1.000000    1.028846    1   1.096970    1.000000    1.101212    1.031157    1.041150    1.049726    1.000000    1.000000    1.055518    1.071197    0.988715    1.019984    1.029829    1.022538    1.000000    1.000000    1.055400    1.213296    1.077197    0.976471    1.000000    0.958823    1.016667    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.024497    0.962932    0.942750    1.068126    1.029828    0.932118    1.015704    1.122137    1.404682    1.031921    1.138117    1.031152    0.986850    1.024615    1.004820    0.944851    1.033674    1.081408    1.129864    1.000593    1.116402    1.000000    1.027211    1.010861    1.000000    1.217009    1.296975    0.998859    1.262970    1.191489    0.980421    0.980759    1.162218    1.087276    1.068555    1.337994    1.000000    1.097952    0.988100    1.056106    1.016367    1.083810    0.980434    1.111111    0.925373    1.008097    1.112971    0.979781    1.015094    1.045833    1.013216    0.937500    1.171914    0.914944    1.016207    1.062687    1.090278    1.120888    1.010375    1   1.244318
11  20061131    1.051444    0.987760    0.977031    1.145765    1.037975    1.101734    1.112500    1.132028    0.902062    1.000000    1.033789    1   0.998158    1.000000    0.986791    0.959233    1.031402    1.026123    1.000000    1.000000    1.088086    1.030909    0.915874    0.958464    1.025804    1.070204    1.000000    1.000000    1.052166    1.200913    1.062770    0.879518    1.000000    1.003067    1.133462    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.056400    1.014542    0.971617    1.049865    1.025978    1.141304    1.007692    1.005442    1.245238    0.993701    1.091525    0.985588    0.891022    0.961864    1.032776    1.035735    1.022836    0.926755    1.160555    0.954821    1.075829    1.000000    0.962472    1.046303    1.000000    1.342651    0.932862    1.003458    1.068046    0.875000    0.983004    1.015804    0.989399    0.945986    1.139336    1.043253    1.000000    1.053528    1.182537    1.059375    0.914286    1.069420    1.058785    1.057143    1.072581    0.947791    1.046940    1.060567    1.011152    0.732271    0.944875    1.083333    1.120903    1.034155    1.072357    0.955524    1.066879    1.029604    0.943207    1   0.971461
12  20061230    0.962706    1.059480    1.035749    1.083725    1.032520    0.988820    0.943820    1.003481    1.075714    1.000000    1.017608    1   1.000000    1.000000    1.016174    1.036000    0.899738    1.017030    1.000000    1.000000    1.032768    1.034941    1.014078    0.953393    1.052583    1.006865    1.000000    1.000000    1.033613    1.188213    0.905548    0.962329    1.000000    1.022209    1.010720    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.055501    1.023667    0.953804    0.956196    1.053260    1.057143    0.977099    0.906631    0.973231    0.992756    0.921118    0.984533    1.062947    1.006923    0.943373    0.970098    1.026068    1.004420    0.994798    0.955321    0.969163    1.000000    1.068807    1.038729    1.000000    1.071788    0.937121    1.049770    1.030534    0.951020    1.041279    0.937768    1.241071    1.012688    1.014893    0.908789    1.000000    1.075559    1.026098    0.970501    0.910541    1.084481    1.009881    0.966216    1.090226    1.084746    1.016413    0.974484    1.033333    1.106638    0.947215    1.076923    0.987509    0.974078    1.019531    0.955468    0.925373    0.968390    0.922033    1   1.024089
13  20070132    1.023279    0.841693    0.874695    0.997101    1.078701    0.703518    0.976190    0.914966    1.188579    1.000000    1.002884    1   1.225092    1.000000    1.074094    0.926641    1.001167    1.033490    1.000000    1.000000    1.203399    1.013287    1.096185    0.973128    1.009947    1.059848    1.000000    1.000000    0.913008    0.980800    0.980724    1.120996    1.000000    1.004828    1.011245    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.980443    0.959672    0.975783    1.022709    0.892590    1.067568    0.968750    1.022388    0.951277    1.001824    1.038436    0.976450    1.017497    1.001875    1.026715    1.093657    1.033670    0.969417    0.896612    1.067392    1.168182    1.000000    0.772532    0.970954    1.000000    1.020261    0.934519    0.934446    1.025926    1.111588    0.991905    1.090103    0.936691    1.063896    0.910775    1.166058    1.000000    1.074313    0.978598    0.851064    1.001252    1.004170    1.215247    1.027972    0.930345    1.269531    0.974006    1.039277    1.028708    0.890855    1.053073    0.969048    1.069569    1.374616    0.962780    0.999482    1.596774    1.079478    0.998183    1   1.091435
14  20070229    1.261621    1.033054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not giving initial values to your matrix, so it is filled with `NA` to start with. Then, multiplying these `NA` with numbers will still give `NA`. You need to initialize it with `1`:

```
hpryearly <- matrix(1, nrow = nrow(datamatrix2)/12, ncol = ncol(datamatrix2))
```

Comment: @user3242036 - if this answered your question, you might like to upvote and/or accept it as the solution :)